# Copy and Paste Macro between worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a macro i am trying to build. The objective of the macro find a name in column A and  then copy information from column D,H,I,K and L .

Currently I am only able to copy the whole row not specific columns.  This information in being pasted in worksheet("Recon").

Below I have a screen shot of worksheet("Recon")  with the headers in this worksheet.  I have put in the column name I am trying to paste in from the other worksheet.

```
Sub CopyRows()
 Dim bottomL As Integer
 bottomL = Sheets("Cash Transactions RBS December ").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Dim c As Range
 For Each c In Sheets("Cash Transactions RBS December ").Range("A1:A" & bottomL)
 If c.Value = "M1 GP LtdEUR" Then ' this should be based on name in cell value H
 c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Recon").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 End If
 Next c
 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: There are several question similar to this. Did you already do some research or just want a solution for your specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, declare  bottomL as Long, integer will cause overflow error in case you have more then 32767 rows. You may not need it now but this is just good practice. If you need values only, do not copy but assign values directy. I would do it this way:

```
With Worksheets("Recon").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).Value = c.EntireRow.Range("D1")
    .Offset(1, 1).Value = c.EntireRow.Range("H1")
    .Offset(1, 2).Value = c.EntireRow.Range("I1")
    'The same for K and L
End With
```

but there are many other possibilities, you could use Offset of Intersect for example.